# Heroku | Internal Server Error and Item could not be created: Unauthorized

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to connect my app to my GitHub but I keep getting this https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/743172330573791282/966744355496939610/unknown.png (I can't post images so I used discord's link thing).
Also any idea why I can't deploy my project either?
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/930141847307833354/966439846107287583/unknown.png

Comment: I'm getting the same thing.

Comment: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413?